# When opening a file through a script I got a different string from what is actually contained

Tags: shell

I have a script which looks into a file like this:

```
for item in `more $dir_tmp/$lcl_ident_cnl.root.tmp`
    do
        txtPos=`expr index "$item" "."`
...
```

This retrieves me this:

```
+ more /gcamp/dbm/processos/temp/tlv.root.tmp
+ expr index :::::::::::::: .
```

BUT, this file actually contains "wca":

```
$ for item in `cat tlv.root.tmp`
> do
>  echo "${item}"
> done
wca
```

The encoding of this file is

```
$ file tlv.root.tmp
tlv.root.tmp: ASCII text
```

Why is it retrieving `::::::::::::::` instead of `wca`?

Comment: Are you trying to read the file one line at a time? One word at a time?

Comment: Line per line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Those colon characters look suspiciously like the prompt **[more(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/more)** gives you when it is waiting for your command.

Programs like `more` are not intended to be scripted, perhaps you should use `cat` in both scripts.

Comment: I totally agree about using `cat` instead of `more`. That was my advice, but they used `more`... =/

Answer (score 1):

A **much** better way would perhaps be

```
while read -r item
do
  txtPos=`expr index "$item" "."`
done < "$dir_tmp/$lcl_ident_cnl.root.tmp"
```

Thanks [`chepner`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841)

Comment: In my example, I wanted it to hold "wca"(as it is shown in the example also) - not ":::::::::".